# Why the animate function hides the other div at the end of animation?

Tags: css

Code can be found there http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/wMQrBR

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  init();
});

function init() {
  $('#test').on('click', function () {
        $('.answer').animate({width: "hide"}, 1000, 'swing');

    });
}
```

**css**:

```
.row {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


.answer {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  width:100%;

  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.answer-new {
  font-size: 40px;
  /* to make answer-new on top and cover answer */
  position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="contrainer">
  <div>
    <input id='test' type='button' value="test"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="answer-new">Under

    </div>
    <div class="answer">Top
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="answer-new">Under1

    </div>
    <div class="answer">Top1
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the page before animation starts

[image]

When the button is clicked, the animation is executed as expected.  I expect div's of css class `answer-new` stay visible. However at the end all the div disappeared.

I tried to use '0' instead of 'hidden'. In this case, the text of div `answer` stays visible. Not completely hidden.

Why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `.row` div have `overflow-x: hidden;` and when `.answer` div width become hidden then there no any div other than `.answer-new`.

And `.answer-new` is `position:absolute` So, it count not width/height. And it will hide all element overflow the `.row`.

To. Make it working add padding to `.row` So, it count some spacing.

like her in example i add `padding: 25px 0;`. and i have give top value to absolute div. `top: 0;` to give it's position.

And added `margin: -25px 0;` to `.answer` to display it proper from top as padding added to parent div.

**CSS:**

```
.row {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
   padding: 25px 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.answer {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  width:100%;

  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -25px 0;
}

.answer-new {
  font-size: 40px;
  /* to make answer-new on top and cover answer */
  position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  top:0;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2h76c6x3/)**

Answer (score 1):

That is because your container div `.row` has no dimension (width nor height) of its own, and the other child div `.answer-row` has absolute positioning and only width dimension. So when the child div `.answer` gets hidden, the parent loses its height dimension, and effectively becomes invisible.

If you give the parent div `.row` a height, when the child div `.answer` gets hidden, the parent stays visible. Consequently the other child div `.answer-row` stays visible, considering its style.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47ddph3L/1/) wherein I added height to `.row`.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't exactly explain the behavior this myself, I took the liberty of limiting the width to 1 px and removing the opacity that fixed the issue

```
function init() {
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    $('.answer').animate({
      width: '1px',
      opacity: 0
    }, 2000, "swing");
  });
}
```

[Updated Fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obJvXW)

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help to you,I used online jquery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<style type="text/css">
 .row {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


.answer {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  width:100%;

  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.answer-new {
  font-size: 40px;
  /* to make answer-new on top and cover answer */
  position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>


<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" id='test' type='button' value="test"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="answer-new">Under

    </div>
    <div class="answer">Top
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="answer-new">Under1

    </div>
    <div class="answer">Top1
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#test").click(function(){
      $(".answer").animate({width:0,opacity:0},1000);
     });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I don't like using jquery/js to animate things, I would do it with css classes

```
.answer {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  width:100%;

  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;

  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.answer.minimized{
  width: 0px;
}
```

in your js

```
$('#test').on('click', function () {
    $('.answer').addClass('minimized');
});
```

Here's the [demo](http://codepen.io/louiealmeda/pen/QyzLNP?editors=0110)